# How to imoprt ldif flle using jndi

Tags: import, ldap, jndi, apacheds, ldif

I am developing an LDAP application, which access APATCHE DIRECTORY I am using JNDI  for interacting with through java code. Now, i am trying to import  information in the format of LDIF from apatcheds to client. how can i do

Comment: Why? Just use the OpenLDAP command line tools. You don't need to write any code for this.

Comment: i 'am actually trying to create an ldap browser so i need to write a code for this